# Adding more validation to django admin user add forms

Tags: django, django-admin

If we need to add more validation in django admin user add form like making the first name and last name and email compulsory.. Whats the way of achieving this??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must create your own user form and adding your required fields:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].required = True
        self.fields['first_name'].required = True
        self.fields['last_name'].required = True
```

Then override the form in your ModelAdmin:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = UserForm
```

And then unregister the normal admin User before registering your own:

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 6):

This extends Geoffroy's answer:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].required = True
        self.fields['first_name'].required = True
        self.fields['last_name'].required = True
```

ModelAdmin:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = UserForm
    add_fieldsets = (
      (None, {'fields':('username','password1','password2','first_name','last_name','email'),}),)
```

And then unregister as above:

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write your own [form class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/) and [tell the ModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/contrib/admin/#form), to use that as the form.